# Using gluing/pasting lemma to show two paths are homotopic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

[image]

($\dot I = \{0,1\}$)

The homotopy I've constructed is:
 $$G(t_1, t_2) =
\begin{cases}
\alpha(t_1),  & \text{if $(t_1,t_2) \in I \times \{0\}$} \\
\gamma * \beta* \delta^{-1}(t_1) , & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

But this isn't correct since the domain of this function isn't a union of two open or closed sets as per the gluing lemma.

Anyone have any ideas as to how to re-write the domain so that this becomes the required homotopy?

Comment: It is better to think about $I \times I$ as a convex set, rather than use gluing.

Comment: @RonnieBrown Can you explain a little more what you mean?  I don't see how the fact that it's convex helps.

Comment: It is a fact that any two paths with the same end points in a convex set $S$  are homotopic rel end points. In your picture of the square, how do you deform $\alpha * \delta$ into $\gamma * \beta$ (assuming these are paths in  $I \times I$ rather than in $X$)?

Comment: I would say by sliding along diagonal lines from upper left to lower right or vice verse, but I'm not sure how I would write a homotopy for this.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the gluing lemma doesn't work:  i.e. $G$ is not continuous unless $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are constant paths.  The question you ask in the bottom is 'can I do something differently to make this map continuous'.  I think the answer is no - the information given $F$ is not used in constructing the homotopy and this information is critical.

One thing related to convexity is that we have the map $r_t: I \times I \to I \times I$, $(s_1,s_2) \mapsto (s_1,ts_2)$. which is a deformation retraction of the inclusion $I \times \{0\} \hookrightarrow I \times I$.  We can use this evidently continuous retraction to construct your homotopy.

Let $\sqcap: I \to I \times I$ be the path with $F \circ (\sqcap)= \gamma * \beta * \delta^{-1}$.  Then because $r_t$ is a deformation retraction $\gamma * \beta * \delta^{-1}= F \circ r_0 \circ  (\sqcap) \cong^{homotopic} F \circ r_1 \circ (\sqcap)  \cong^{homotopic} \alpha $.

The homotopy of the first equivalence is  $h_t=F \circ r_t \circ (\sqcap)$.  The homotopy of the second equivalence is the homotopy (identity path at $(0,0)$) $* \alpha *$(identity path at $(1,0)$) $ \cong \alpha$.

---

Edit:  Above I wrote a crap answer.  Prof. Brown has the right idea.  Let $\text{_____}$ be the path given by $\text{_____}(t)=(t,0)$ in $I \times I$.  Then there is a homotopy $g_t$ from $\sqcap$ to $\text{_____}$.
$h_t=F \circ g_t$ is a homotopy from $\gamma * \beta * \delta^{-1}$ to $\alpha$.

Comment: I'm a little confused:  If $r_t: (I \times I) \times I \rightarrow I \times \{0\}$ by $(s_1, s_2, t) \rightarrow (s_1, ts_2)$, then this doesn't seem to be a map to $I \times \{0\}$ since for $t=1$ and $s_2 \neq 0$ the image isn't in $I \times \{0\}$?

Comment: So if $j : I \rightarrow I \times \{0\}$ and $\sqcap : I \rightarrow I \times I$ by $\sqcap$ mapping the unit interval around the three edges of the square, then they're homotopic ($g_t$) since they're two paths in a path connected space that share boundary points.  Therefore $h_t = F \circ g_t$ is the required homotopy?

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a simply connected space and let $g: S \to X$ be a map. Let $a,b: [0,1] \to S$ be paths in $S$ with the same end points. Then $ga,gb: [0,1] \to X$ are homotopic rel end points.

**Proof** Since $S$ is simply connected there is a homotopy $H_t:a \simeq b$ rel end points. Then $gH_t:ga \simeq gb$.

In the case we need, $S$ is a square. It is convex and we can define $H_t(s)= (1-t)a(s) + t b(t)$. Then $H_0(s) =a(s), H_1(s) = b(s)$.